# How to implement in a pipe a search and a highlighting?

Tags: angular

After several unsuccessful searches, I would like to know if there is the possibility in a pipe to associate a search function and a highlighting function.

The only example I found and this one :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe-8q9jyc

who does the research and highlighting but in two different pipe.

Maybe the use of the pipe may not be the right solution for both these features.

Can be go through a service or component ....

If you have any solutions that could teach me I'm a taker

Comment: At minimum it is recommend to NOT use a pipe for filtering or sorting. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I just read the article actually it is not recommended to use the pipe for filters, but are there other solutions other than pipes?

Comment: Yes, you can simply sort/filter data on the component/service using Array.prototype.sort, Array.prototype.filter, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass another argument to the pipe to highlight your contents, along with search term if you choose to

**Pipe**

```
transform(list: any[], searchText: string, highlight?: boolean): any[] {
  if (!list) { return []; }
  if (!searchText) { return list; }

  searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
  let response = list.filter( item => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
  });

  if(highlight) {
    response = response.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      name: this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
        item.name.replace(searchText, `<span style='background-color:yellow'>${searchText}</span>`)
      ) 
    }));
  }
  return response;
}
```

**Template**:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: searchedTerm : doHighlight">
  <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>
</div>
```

you can pass multiple arguments to pipe separated by `:` here I am passing a second argument `doHighlight=true` wishing to highlight my filtered matches, If you choose not to highlight them just pass `doHighlight=false` or don't pass anything as highlight is an optional argument.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe-bmzzez